# Uploading file, axios works but fetch API doesn't, what did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, axios, fetch-api

I'm using fetch API to communicate with the server, then I realize when I use fetch API to upload file, the post request looks weird and my PHP server couldn't get the file by `$_FILES` correctly.

Here's my basic setup, the `file` and `fileName` are pre-populated.

```js
const api = 'xxxx/api/file';
const body = new FormData();
body.append('files[]', file, fileName);
body.append('bid', 529);

const headers = { 
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 
  'Authorization': 'Token xxxxxx'
};
```

---

While I'm using fetch API, the post request looks like this, any my PHP server couldn't get the post data.

```js
fetch(api, { method: 'POST', body, headers, mode: 'cors' });
```

[image]

---

But when I use axios, the request looks like this, and my PHP server could get the files correctly:

```js
axios.post(api, body, { headers });
```

[image]

---

So what is going on? Did axios do something different?

And is there a way to achieve this without using axios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the fetch API without the `content-Type` key:

```
const api = 'xxxx/api/file';
const body = new FormData();
body.append('files[]', file, fileName);
body.append('bid', 529);

const headers = { 
  'Authorization': 'Token xxxxxx'
};

delete headers.headers['Content-Type'];

fetch(api, { method: 'POST', body, headers, mode: 'cors' });
```

Source: https://muffinman.io/blog/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/

Comment: I also tried it, the result is the same. The `content-type: multipart/form-data` is added automatically somehow

Comment: @HaoWu Content type is taken care by FormData automatically.

Comment: @HaoWu The issue with the fetch request is that the boundary parameter is missing. Without the boundary PHP can't parse it, and the boundary is likely missing because you are overriding the `Content-Type`

Comment: Turns out it was me accidentally assigning the `content-type` somewhere else. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The reason that why axios works is because axios ignores `content-type` header when `FormData` is the payload, I think.